# Gradients in deepdream

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, theano, deep-dream

I'm trying to implement deepdream in theano. As far as I understood I need to choose a layer in a pre-trained neural network to be the objective , then I need to set the activation functions of that layer to be equal to gradients, then backpropagate to the input image and finally apply the changes.
I'm new to theano and I can't think of how to implement it, how can I set the layer's values to be equal to gradients and backpropagate back to image? Is it possible to do in a couple of lines in theano?
Also if my understanding is wrong, please correct me.